# BR/RET timing discrepancy when returning from contrived subroutine to a modified return address

Tags: assembly, arm, arm64, branch-prediction

In my adventures of experimenting around with the 64-bit ARM architecture, I noticed a peculiar speed difference depending on whether `br` or `ret` is used to return from a subroutine.

```
; Contrived for learning/experimenting purposes only, without any practical use
foo:
    cmp     w0, #0
    b.eq    .L0
    sub     w0, w0, #1
    sub     x30, x30, #4
    ret
.L0:
    ret ; Intentionally duplicated 'ret'
```

The intent of this subroutine is to make the caller of `foo` "reenter" `foo` `w0` times by making `foo` return to the instruction that called `foo` in the first place (i.e. the instruction immediately before the one to which `x30` points). With some rough timing, with `w0` being some sufficiently high value, it took about 1362 milliseconds on average. Curiously, replacing the first `ret` with `br x30` makes it run over twice as fast, taking only 550 milliseconds or so on average.

The timing discrepancy goes away if the test is simplified to just repeatedly calling a subroutine with a bare `ret`/`br x30`. What makes the above contrived subroutine slower with a `ret`?

I tested this on some kind of ARMv8.2 (Cortex-A76 + Cortex-A55) processor. I'm not sure to what extent big.LITTLE would mess with the timings, but they seemed pretty consistent over multiple runs. This is by no means a real [micro]benchmark, but instead a "roughly how long does this take if run N times" thing.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Most modern microarchitectures have a special predictor for call / return, which tend to match up with each other in real programs.  (And predicting returns any other way is hard for functions with many call-sites: it's an indirect branch.)

By playing with the return address manually, you're making those return-predictions wrong.  So every `ret` causes a branch mispredict, except the one where you didn't play with `x30`.

But if you use an indirect branch other than the one recognized specifically as a `ret` idiom, e.g. `br x30`, the CPU uses its standard indirect-branch prediction method, which does well when the `br` goes to the same location repeatedly.

---

A quick google search found some info from ARM for Cortex-R4 about the return-predictor stack on that microarchitecture for 32-bit mode (a 4-entry circular buffer): https://developer.arm.com/documentation/ddi0363/e/prefetch-unit/return-stack

For x86, https://blog.stuffedcow.net/2018/04/ras-microbenchmarks/ is a good article about the concept in general, as well as some details on how various x86 microarchitectures maintain their prediction accuracy in the face of things like mis-speculated execution of a `call` or `ret` instruction that has to get rolled back.

(x86 has an actual `ret` opcode; ARM64 is the same: the `ret` opcode is like `br`, but with a hint that this is a function-return.  Some other RISCs like RISC-V don't have a separate opcode, and just assume that branch-to-register with the link register is a return.)